# Keep two first text lines, remove everything else

Tags: php, jquery, html, line-breaks

In a `<div>` I have some text. Because of the `div`-width the text is shown in multiple lines. E.g. the following code:

```
<div>text01 text02 text03 text04 text05 text06 text07 text08 text09 text10 text11 text12</div>
```

might be shown in e.g. four lines:

```
text01 text02 text03
text04 text05 text06
text07 text08 text09
text10 text11 text12
```

I wish to keep only the first two lines, and if further lines are present they must be removed and replaced with the text line `...` as a new (therefore third) text line.
In other words: I wish to find the second line break (if present) and replace all text after this point with a text line saying `...`.

So, if I have two lines of text, nothing is changed:

```
text text text
text text text
```

But if I have more than two lines like above, I will get this:

```
text01 text02 text03
text04 text05 text06
...
```

Any good advice?

Comment: Doing it PHP side (ie server side) isn't easy, as the line size will vary depending on client resolution.

Comment: So some javascript is needed?

Comment: I have edited and added the jquery tag. Thanks.

Comment: Even with JavaScript this is going to be difficult to achieve properly. You basically have to calculate the text width when all in one line, then you need to get the difference from the desired div width and then approximate the character count to sub off.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should do that in **css** and if necessary add javascript.

In css you can set:

```
.two-line-div {
  max-height: 3em;    /* or whatever adds up to 2 times your line-height */
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

That will reduce the box to the desired height.

If you always want to show `...` (if the content is always more than 2 lines), just add an element with the three dots after your `div`.

If you want to add another line with `...` if the content is bigger than what you are showing, you would need javascript to calculate the original height, see if it is more than 2 lines and add / show an element dynamically if it is.

Note that a css solution does not remove anything, all lines are there, they are just not visible.

Comment: Thanks. I actually need it to be more dynamic than this; if there is just one line, then the surrounding `div` box should also be just one line height high, instead of being permanently say 3em in height.

Comment: @Steeven That is automatic, I am using `max-height` instead of `height` so with only one line, but box will just be one line. `max-height` tells the box to grow until a certain maximum.

Answer (score 0):

There is a pure CSS Solution working in most of the modern browsers (some older firefox versions didn't support it):

```
div {
    overflow: hidden; /* "overflow" value must be different from "visible" */
    text-overflow: ellipsis; /* the magic dots...*/
    height: <yourHeightValue>
    width: <yourWidthValue>
}
```

Doing something like this in PHP could be a bit more complex, depending on what the DIV contains (nested HTML?, what exactly is a "line" for you -> a HTML break <br>, a line-break \n)? In most of the cases the PHP solutions split after a defined String or Word length. You can find quite a few examples for this kind of text limitations, [this one](http://www.gsdesign.ro/blog/cut-html-string-without-breaking-the-tags/) is a complex solution which can handle html tags too.

Comment: `ellipsis` sounds better that it actually is; it only works for one line, not for multiple lines.

Comment: It is text lines of pure text, no html. If the `ellipsis` works vertically and not just horizontally, this is perfect. I can't make it do that, though...

Comment: yes, you are right, forgot about that. Ellipsis is still unusable in a multi-line context.

Comment: There is a jQuery plugin for multiline ellipsis http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/, as long as CSS won't give you a chance.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `explode()` to split your string (the contents of the `div`) into an array. Use `<br>` or `/n` as the split token. Then you can replace the contents of the `div` with the first two elements of the array.

```
$content = 'Hello<br>World<br>Other<br>Stuff';
$lines = explode('<br>',$content,2);

echo '<div>'$lines[0].'<br>'.$lines[1].'<br>...</div>'
```

Comment: But if my text line is just: `$content = 'Hello World Other Stuff';` without any `<br>`, will the script then be able to pick out the `\n` that are automatically added?

Comment: You can use nl2br($content);

Comment: I can't make this work.  
A count with `$a=explode('<br>',nl2br($content)); echo count($a)` only counts the already existing linebreaks that are in the text. It doesn't see the line breaks caused by wrapping the text inside the `div`.